# how can i fix google trans ios web-view cookie problem?

Tags: ios, webview, google-api, google-translate

hello i am having hard time on ios web view.
i want to use google translate but it doesnt work on ios app.
my site works well on chrome, safari, android app or other browser.
BUT! not working on ios app.
how can i fix this problem?

common.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var langOpt = "";
    var tolang = "";

    //lang cookie add
    if (localStorage.getItem("langOpt")) {
        langOpt = localStorage.getItem("langOpt").split("+");
        tolang = langOpt[1];
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("langOpt", "KR+ko+KRW");
        tolang = "ko";
    }    
    
    $.cookie("googtrans", "/auto/"+tolang);    
    document.cookie="googtrans=/auto/"+tolang;
});

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        autoDisplay: true,
        includedLanguages: "en,ko,zh-CN",
        multilanguagePage: true
    }, "google_translate_element");
}
```

main.js

```
//lang change
function changeLanguage(){
    var country = $("input[name=shpng]:checked").val();
    var lang = $("input[name=lang]:checked").val();
    var currency = $("input[name=crcy]:checked").val();

    localStorage.setItem("langOpt", country+"+"+lang+"+"+currency );
    location.href='/change-language/'+country+'/'+lang+'/'+currency;

    fn_googleTranslate();   
}


function fn_googleTranslate() { 
    var tolang = $("input[name=lang]:checked").val();
    var gtcombo = document.querySelector('.goog-te-combo');

    gtcombo.value = tolang; // 변경할 언어 적용
    gtcombo.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // 변경 이벤트 트리거
}
```

i heard because of ios security Policy..?
i cannot use cookie. so i changed everything cookie to localStorage.
but
`document.cookie="googtrans=/auto/"+tolang;`
i dont know how to change this one.
when i search about it, google translate reads that cookie to translate.

please Help

Thank you